# Disk read error occurre

Tags: windows

Всем привет! Появилась такая проблема, и уже не знаю, что можно делать. В Биосе жёсткий диск виден, через акронис понкта "зарезервировано системой" просто нет, но диск С, активен. Пробывал переподключать на другие разъёмы SATA, и это тоже не исправило. Что это тогда может быть и как это исправить? Кстати, стоит Windows 7.

Comment: `ERD` прогружал?

Comment: Ещё нет, не успел

Comment: @don Rumata начал проверять его с помощью ERD, но он вообще не видит жёсткий диск и систему. Но когда нажал загрузить драйвер, то увидел что для того что бы открыть диск "С", то он требует его предварительно отформатировать, но любой другой диск я открыть могу. Что это может быть?

Comment: Ммм... а gparted live что показывает?